# groupBy returns only 1 result set of that particular id in QueryBuilder laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, laravel-5

I have 2 Models: `Product` and `Carousel`. Both of them have `Many To Many` relationship established.

I have a `pivot` table `carousel_product`.

In the pivot table, I have few datas like so:

```
id    carousel_id    product_id    created_at    updated_at
 1         2              2           --             --
 2         2              3           --             --
 3         2              4           --             --
 4         2              5           --             --
 5         2              6           --             --
 6         3              7           --             --
 7         3              8           --             --
 8         3              9           --             --
 9         3             10           --             --
10         3             11           --             --
```

Now I want to retrieve all the products that are in `carousel_id = 2` and `carousel_id = 3`

For this, I am using Query Builder in my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $carousels = Carousel::where('display', 'Enabled')->get();
    $products = DB::table('carousel_product AS cp')
                ->join('products AS p', 'p.id', '=', 'cp.product_id')
                ->join('carousels AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'cp.carousel_id')
                ->select(
                    'p.id AS prod_id',
                    'p.name AS prod_name',
                    'p.code AS prod_code',
                    'p.short_description AS prod_short_desc',
                    'p.price AS prod_price',
                    'p.discount_price AS prod_disc_price'
                )->groupBy('cp.carousel_id')->get();
    dd( $products );
    return view( 'home', compact( 'carousels', 'products' ) );
}
```

The output of `dd( $products )` is `product_id` of `2` and `7`

I want all the products of that particular `carousel_id` and display it in my view for that carousel only.

**P.S.:** All the values are coming from the database.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` is an aggregate function. The behaviour you describe if exactly how it's supposed to work - it combines all rows with the same `cp.carousel_id` into one and allows you to do aggregate functions like `MAX`, `SUM`, `AVG`, etc. against the set.

> Now I want to retrieve all the products that are in carousel_id = 2 and carousel_id = 3

You want `whereIn('carousel_id', [2, 3])` for that.

Comment: Did nothing.. It returned everything about the product that I passed in `select()` method without any group of `carousel_id`. Meaning it returned every product from `product_id = 2` to `product_id = 11`. If you don't mind, can you please help me with the code ?